# issue with convert decimal to string in dart language

Tags: flutter, dart, utf-8

I want to read incoming data from Bluetooth connection and should convert these DEC data to string but it gives the error in line 11 (`snapshot.data`)

> The argument type `'List<int>?'` can't be assigned to the parameter type `'List<int>'`

How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<int>>(
      stream: characteristic.value,
      initialData: characteristic.lastValue,
      builder: (c, snapshot) {
        final value = snapshot.data;

        String _dataParser(List<int> dataFromDevice) {
          return utf8.decode(dataFromDevice);
        }
        var currentValue = _dataParser(snapshot.data);

        return ExpansionTile(
          title: ListTile(
            title: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text('Characteristic'),
                Text(
                    '0x${characteristic.uuid.toString().toUpperCase().substring(4, 8)}',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge?.copyWith(
                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.color))
              ],
            ),
            subtitle: Text(value.toString()),
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          ),
          children: descriptorTiles,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check that `snapshot.data` isn't `null` before passing it to `_dataParser`, something like

```
   if (snapshot.data != null){
      //return an error or something
   } else {
      var currentValue = _dataParser(snapshot.data!); //note the ! here
      //proceed with your logic...
   }
```

Otherwise, if you're really sure that `snapshot.data` will never ever ever be `null`, you can simply add a `!` like this

```
var currentValue = _dataParser(snapshot.data!);
```

Beware that this will throw a unchecked exception if at some point `snapshot.data` happens to be `null`, though.